# How to use a csv file as input for basic arithmetic operations in bash

Tags: bash, csv, math

I've stored my data in `neckrev_dim.csv` file, structured like the following

```
subjectID,dim3,pixdim3 
MR44825,405,0.625
```

I also have a seperate `subjects.csv`, just containing all the subjectIDs

```
MR44825
MR55843
```

Now I want to use this data in basic arithmetic operations using bash.

```
subjlist=subjects.csv
for subj in ` cat $subjlist `
do
    dim3=$(grep -w '$subj' neckrev_dim.csv | cut -d ',' -f 2)
    pixdim3=$(grep -w '$subj' neckrev_dim.csv | cut -d ',' -f 3)
    total_length=$(($dim3*$pixdim3))
    echo $total_length
done
```

This leads to the following error:

```
syntax error: operand expected (error token is "*")
```

I think the problem lies within the `grep`, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that POSIX arithmetic does not support decimals, only integers.

You will have to use something else, like [`bc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html) for non-integer arithmetic.

The other issue is that you are single-quoting `$subj` -- you should use double quotes so the variable gets expanded.

Try the following:

```
subjlist=subjects.csv

while read -r subj
do
    dim3=$(grep -w "$subj" neckrev_dim.csv | cut -d ',' -f 2)
    pixdim3=$(grep -w "$subj" neckrev_dim.csv | cut -d ',' -f 3)
    echo "$dim3 * $pixdim3" | bc
done < "$subjlist"
```

Note, here `bc` is reading from standard input, so we just need to `echo` the arithmetic expression to `bc`.

Comment: Works perfectly as well! Thanks for solution and the explanation for where I'm making the mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the single quotes to double quotes around the `$subj`. Single quotes won't expand the variable.

Comment: Ah, perfect, thanks a lot! This already solved my first issue. Now only problem is, that I stored `pixdim3` as a decimal using `.`, so it's throwing me another error `497*0.400024: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".400024")`. Would you know a easy fix for that?

Comment: Bash can't handle floating point... try `total=$(dc -e "$dim3 $pixdim3 * p")`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution below is designed to work accurately and more generally for different types of key values and different CSV lines, avoiding some of the limitations and failure modes of the other solutions.

## Description of the code

Using single key fields read one per line from file `keys.txt`, search for the key in the first field in a CSV file `generic.csv` and do some floating-point (non-integer) math on the numbers in the other fields.

## Performance enhancements:

1. If `$key` selects a unique row in the file, change `XexitX` below to `exit` so that `awk` doesn't keep reading the rest of the file unnecessarily; otherwise, delete `XexitX` and it will do all the lines matching that key.
2. If `generic.csv` is a large file, then sort it and replace the `awk` line with the `look --binary` line. This will replace a linear search with a binary search.  Make sure you sort the *whole* file:
   `sort -o generic.csv generic.csv`

## Limitations:

1. The `$key` key must not contain backslashes or double quotes in the `awk` version.  This could be fixed using `sed -e 's/\\/&&/g' -e 's/"/\\"/g'` on the field.  The `look --binary` version doesn't care.
2. The `generic.csv` file must use commas only, no "quoted" CSV fields.  This means no fields may contain commas.
3. The `look --binary` version does key prefix matching on the CSV lines, so you can't have a key that is a prefix of another, e.g. keys `ABC` and `AB` aren't distinct.  The `awk` version doesn't have this problem.

## Advantages of this over other solutions:

1. Reads the CSV only once per key, not multiple times.
2. The `$key` is matched exactly on the first field and not on any fields that might be added to the rest of the CSV line - no false matches.  (The `look --binary` version does do prefix matching, so you can't have a key that is a prefix of another.)
3. The key field is a text field, not a regular expression, so it may contain special characters without any need to worry about escaping regular expression metacharacters to avoid errors.
4. No need to use `grep` or `cut` to separate fields; only one pipe, not three.
5. Can easily scale up to huge CSV files by using `look --binary` instead of `awk`.

```
while read -r key ; do
    # SEE NOTES: look --binary "$key" generic.csv \
    awk -F, "\$1 == \"$key\" { print ; XexitX }" generic.csv \
        | while IFS=, read -r key num1 num2  ; do
            echo "$key: $(dc -e "$num1 $num2 * p")"
        done
done <keys.txt
```